# How to Post BASE64 string using mulesoft

Tags: post, request, base64, transformation, mulesoft

So I receive plain text which contains image coded in base64 format. 
String I receive from request IMG :

[image]

Example :

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNkYPhfDwAChwGA60e6kgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

I need to post this string  to https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key={key} 
I am able to send it manually in by using ARC 
ARC Sending request IMG :

[image]

I need to send this plain string using Mulesoft I tryed many ways : 
my post request :

[image]

```
<flow name="reciveProfilePicture" doc:id="a1b3f198-c5e3-4e8d-b309-f69e9e0552f4">

</ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
</ee:transform>

        <http:request method="POST" doc:name="Request" doc:id="dc91be5d-bbfc-4ce3-834c-a1b93569add5" url="https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=c7756bd8c7786364112046dd9694d5fd" responseTimeout="10000">
            <http:body ><![CDATA[#[image : payload]]]></http:body>
        </http:request>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="e831fa15-cc87-495d-aeaf-03b761ba0ea8" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
```

> Error: "HTTP POST on resource
>   'https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key={key}' failed: bad request (400)."

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiZm5.png   String I receive from request
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/shZxt.png  ARC Sending request
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9olFB.png my post request

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data needs to be send into an HTTP attachment (multipart/form-data). See an example of how to do that in the Mule 4 example at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/migration-connectors-http#http_multipart